# How to solve the issue with pandas-datareader?

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

after istalling pandas-datareader I have this issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRmSb.jpg)

what's the problem?

Comment: Please post your error message as text within your question, so it is easier to search and read. If your screenshot link goes down in the future, this question will become useless as currently worded.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the pandas_datareader library. You need to install it via pip. See the [documentation here](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

Comment: You may have installed it but your current interpretter in PyCharm is not looking in the right place.